# How To map a network Drive through preferences by using wmi in server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

I want to map a network drive through Group Policy Preferences option. For this mapping i want to go with wmi query, which is in item level targeting. I am done with all the initial work like giving its path, drive letter etc.

Now on the common tab I selected item level targeting. In which i selected wmi query and i wrote the query as `select username from win32_ComputerSystem where domain="www.test.com"`. I am running windows server 2008, my domain is www.test.com and i am using windows 7 machine as client of my server.

After applying the preferences i ran `gpupdate /force` also on client an then log off and log on but i am not getting the network drive on my client. Did I write the wmi query wrong or anything else?

Comment: What is your full wmi query?

Comment: My Full query is select username from win32_ComputerSystem where domain="www.test.com".

Comment: What is the objective of the Item level targeting? I personally would avoid using WMI as it does add a delay for slower computers.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but why are you using WMI to do this when GPP Item Level Targeting has a built in "Domain" option? I'd just use that.